# Find object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a nsted array of objects

```
0: "0"
1: Array(3)
  0: {Situation A: "5.0"}
  1: {Situation B: "4.0"}
  2: {Situation C: 0}
0: "1"
1: Array(3)
  0: {Situation B: "6.0"}
  1: {Situation C: "4.0"}
  2: {Situation A: 2.0}
...
```

I would get an array with values of `Situation B` for exemple`

Here's the output expected ( array of values )

```
0: "4.0"
1: "6.0"
```

Here's how I made

```
this.data = _.isArray(this.valuesCopy) // check if array
  ? this.valuesCopy.map(_val => { // then 
    let value
      if (_val[1] !== null) {
         value =_val[1].filter(obj => {
          if(Object.keys(obj).find(key=>key=="Situation B")) { // check if Situation B exist
            return obj;
          }
        });
      }
      return value[0]["Situation B"]

    })
  : []
```

In my console I get an error

```
 Cannot read property 0' of undefined
```

Comment: Your expected output does not match "Situation B"

Comment: @infodev it should be `0: "4.0"
1: "6.0"`

Comment: You should post real javascript code not the copy/pasted output from the browser console. It's really hard to tell what the actual structure of your array(s) is.

Comment: the problem is in your  `return value[0]["Situation B"]` .. value here could still be `undefined`, considering your if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can either do a recursive function, or flatten, filter, and map.

Here's the flatten, filter, and map version using the new [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method of arrays (you can polyfill it if necessary):

```
const result = this.valuesCopy
                .flat(2)
                .filter(obj => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "Situation B"))
                .map(obj => obj["Situation B"]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const valuesCopy = [
    "0",
    [
      {"Situation A": "5.0"},
      {"Situation B": "4.0"},
      {"Situation C": 0}
    ],
    "1",
    [
      {"Situation B": "6.0"},
      {"Situation C": "4.0"},
      {"Situation A": 2.0}
    ]
];
const result = valuesCopy
                .flat(2)
                .filter(obj => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "Situation B"))
                .map(obj => obj["Situation B"]);
console.log(result);
```

Or a recursive solution:

```
function deepPick(data, propName, resultArray = []) {
    for (const entry of data) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
            deepPick(entry, propName, resultArray);
        } else if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(entry, propName)) {
            resultArray.push(entry[propName]);
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}

const result = deepPick(this.valuesCopy, "Situation B");
```

Live Example:

```js
function deepPick(data, propName, resultArray = []) {
    for (const entry of data) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
            deepPick(entry, propName, resultArray);
        } else if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(entry, propName)) {
            resultArray.push(entry[propName]);
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
}

const valuesCopy = [
    "0",
    [
      {"Situation A": "5.0"},
      {"Situation B": "4.0"},
      {"Situation C": 0}
    ],
    "1",
    [
      {"Situation B": "6.0"},
      {"Situation C": "4.0"},
      {"Situation A": 2.0}
    ]
];
const result = deepPick(valuesCopy, "Situation B");
console.log(result);
```

---

Obviously you can tweak the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(x, name)` thing as desired. You might add `typeof x === "object" &&` in front of it, for instance, to avoid having `hasOwnProperty` creating an object if the entry isn't one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using Array#flat, Array#map, Array#filter and destructruing.

```js
const data = [
    [
      {"Situation A": "5.0"}, {"Situation B": "4.0"}, {"Situation C": 0}
    ],
    [
      {"Situation B": "6.0"}, {"Situation C": "4.0"}, {"Situation A": 2.0}
    ]
]

const res = data
  .flat()
  .map(Object.entries)
  .flat()
  .filter(([k])=>k==="Situation B")
  .map(([,v])=>v);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted I'm assuming this is your structure. You could do something like this using [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and `filter`

```js
const valuesCopy = [
    ["0", [{
        "Situation A": "5.0"
      },
      {
        "Situation B": "4.0"
      },
      {
        "Situation C": 0
      }
    ]],
    ["1", [{
        "Situation B": "6.0"
      },
      {
        "Situation C": "4.0"
      },
      {
        "Situation A": 2.0
      }
    ]]
  ];

const output = valuesCopy.map(a => a[1] ? a[1] : [])
  .flat()
  .filter(a => "Situation B" in a)
  .map(a => a["Situation B"])
  
  console.log(output)
```

If `flat` [isn't supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) in your browser yet:

```
const output = [].concat(...valuesCopy.map(a => a[1] ? a[1] : []))
  .filter(a => "Situation B" in a)
  .map(a => a["Situation B"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [**flat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = [[{"Situation A": "5.0"}, {"Situation B": "4.0"}, {"Situation C": 0}],[{"Situation B": "6.0"}, {"Situation C": "4.0"}, {"Situation A": 2.0}]]

const res = data.flat()
  .reduce((op,inp)=>{
    if(Object.keys(inp)[0] === 'Situation B'){
      op.push(inp['Situation B'])
    }
    return op
  },[])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be elegant solution, but you can try

```
const ar = [
  [
   '0',
    [{ 'Situation A': '5.0' }, { 'Situation B': '4.0' 
     }, { 'Situation C': 0 }]
  ],
 [
   1,
   [{ 'Situation B': '6.0' }, { 'Situation C': '4.0' 
    }, { 'Situation C': 2.0 }]
   ]
 ];

const output = [];
ar.forEach(ele => {
 ele[1].forEach(arData => {
  if (arData.hasOwnProperty('Situation B')) {
  output.push(arData['Situation B']);
    }
  });
});


console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the sub arrays, check if the key is in the object, and if it is add the result to an array.

```
var arrs = [[{"Situation A": "5.0"},
              {"Situation B": "4.0"},
              {"Situation C": 0}],
              [{"Situation B": "6.0"},
              {"Situation C": "4.0"},
              {"Situation A": 2.0}]];

var key = "Situation B";

var matches = [];
arrs.forEach(function(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(o) {
    if (key in o) {
      matches.push(o[key]);
    }
  })
})

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not entirely clear what the full structure of your data is. I assume:

```js
const values = [
    [
        "0",
        [
            {"Situation A": "foo"},
            {"Situation B": "bar"},
            {"Situation C": "baz"}
        ]
    ],
    [
        "1",
        [
            {"Situation A": "foo"},
            {"Situation B": "bar"},
            {"Situation C": "baz"}
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

I think this should work:

```js
values
  .map(x => x[1] || [])
  .flat()
  .filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('Situation B') && x['Situation B'])
  .map(x => x['Situation B'])
```